# sort keys in arbitrary order

Tags: json, sorting, dictionary, jq

For a side-project I want to sort the keys of a JSON with jq, and come up with the following solution:

```
def add_property_prefix:
    if .key == "beka" then "01__"+.key
    elif .key == "alma" then "02__"+.key
    elif .key == "paprika" then "03__"+.key
    elif .key == "korte" then "04__"+.key
    else .key end
;

def del_property_prefix:
    .key | sub("^[0-9]{2}__"; "")
;

to_entries
| map({ key: add_property_prefix, value: .value })
| sort_by(.key)
| map({ key: del_property_prefix, value: .value })
| from_entries
```

And the input JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "alma": 1,
    "beka": 2,
    "paprika": 3,
    "korte": 4
}
```

([jq play link](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=def%20add_property_prefix%3A%20if%20.key%20%3D%3D%20%22beka%22%20then%20%2201__%22%2B.key%20elif%20.key%20%3D%3D%20%22alma%22%20then%20%2202__%22%2B.key%20elif%20.key%20%3D%3D%20%22paprika%22%20then%20%2203__%22%2B.key%20elif%20.key%20%3D%3D%20%22korte%22%20then%20%2204__%22%2B.key%20else%20.key%20end%3B%20def%20del_property_prefix%3A%20.key%20%7C%20sub(%22%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D__%22%3B%20%22%22)%3B%20to_entries%20%7C%20map(%7B%20key%3A%20add_property_prefix%2C%20value%3A%20.value%20%7D)%20%7C%20sort_by(.key)%20%7C%20map(%7B%20key%3A%20del_property_prefix%2C%20value%3A%20.value%20%7D)%20%7C%20from_entries&j=%7B%22alma%22%3A1%2C%22beka%22%3A2%2C%22paprika%22%3A3%2C%22korte%22%3A4%7D))

While this works, I have more than 10 keys and the `add_property_prefix` function is really bloaty because of this.

**The question: is there a way to make sorting list less redundant?**

I was thinking of some kind of map, but I don't know jq that much to figure out a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify the keys and their order:

```
 { beka, alma, paprika, korte }
```

### Caveat

This only works for keys with "ordinary" names.  For example, since `end` is a jq keyword, you would have to write:

```
{ "end": .end}
```

for a key named "end", at least using extant versions of jq.

Comment: @oguzismail - Please undelete your answer, which illustrates a strategy that can be useful under various circumstances, e.g. if the list of keys is available as a stream or array.