# Sort keys in arbitrary order and keeping unknown keys

Tags: json, sorting, dictionary, jq

Follow-up question to [sort keys in arbitrary order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60886010/sort-keys-in-arbitrary-order):

With the help of [oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail) I can sort an object based on the keys even in non-alphabetical order ([accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60886427/1423815), [online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wj2hohQK2F)):

```sh
$ echo '{ "alma": 1, "beka": 2, "paprika": 3, "korte": 4, "cekla": 5 }' | jq '. as $in | reduce ("beka", "alma", "paprika", "korte") as $k ({}; .[$k] = $in[$k])'
{
  "beka": 2,
  "alma": 1,
  "paprika": 3,
  "korte": 4
}
```

Even though the code is quite elegant, it removes all non-listed keys.

**Question: How can I keep unknown keys in the output at the end of the JSON to have the following output?**

```
{
  "beka": 2,
  "alma": 1,
  "paprika": 3,
  "korte": 4,
  "cekla": 5
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [peak's answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60889140/10248678):

```
{ beka, alma, paprika, korte } + .
```